# Missing comma in my SQL command

Tags: sql

I am somewhat stuck even after looking at all the duplicate questions of this one...

```
INSERT INTO membership_type(member_type_name,benefits,special rates)
VALUES ('silver', 'Free WI-fi', '0.9')
```

This gives me a missing comma error. Any idea how do I solve the issue?

Comment: `special rates` should be `"special rates"` you need to quote names with non-standard characters. Plus numbers do not need to be put into single quotes. `0.9` is a number, `'0.9'` is a character value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `special rates` to `special_rates`.

Comment: Not quite true if the column name really is "special rates" (with space).

Answer (score 1):

Add an `_` to special rates to bring it in line with your multiple word naming convention e.g.`(member_type_name)`.

Also numbers don't need single quotes

```
INSERT INTO membership_type(member_type_name,benefits,special_rates)
VALUES ('silver', 'Free WI-fi', 0.9)
```